# win condition in tic tac toe game java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

hey i made and tic tac toe game (oh here we go again... :) ) but i have issues with my win condition, *isGameOver* method returns true whatever i choose and i cant figure out why. Any tips? Iident think that it compares spaces as an identical characters, but im not so sure...

```
public class zadanie16 {
public static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
public static int row, column;
public static char turn = 'x';

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initializeBoard();
    play();
}

public static char[][] initializeBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }

    }
    return board;
}

public static void printBoard() {
    System.out.println("/---|---|---\\");
    System.out.println("| " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " |");
    System.out.println("|-----------|");
    System.out.println("| " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " |");
    System.out.println("|-----------|");
    System.out.println("| " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " |");
    System.out.println("/---|---|---\\");
}

public static void play() {
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    while (isPlaying) {
        System.out.println("Podaj wiersz");
        row = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        System.out.println("Podaj kolumne");
        column = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
        board[row][column] = turn;
        if (isGameOver(row, column)) {
            isPlaying = false;
            System.out.println("Gratulations player" + turn + " wins!");
        }

        printBoard();
        if (turn == 'x') {
            turn = 'o';
        } else {
            turn = 'x';
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isGameOver(int rowMove, int columnMove) {
    if (board[0][columnMove] == board[0][columnMove] && board[0][columnMove] == board[0][columnMove]) {
        return true;
    }
    if (board[rowMove][0] == board[rowMove][0] && board[rowMove][0] == board[rowMove][2]) {
        return true;
    }


    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: In your first `if` statement you have this condition repeated twice: `board[0][columnMove] == board[0][columnMove]`. You probably didn't mean to repeat it, but not only that, you're checking an object against itself for equality, which will always result in `true`. You also have the same problem with `board[rowMove][0] == board[rowMove][0]` in the next `if` statement, but without the repetition.

Comment: oh wow, i feel so stupid right now. It was it, seriously :) Thank you @JonK

Comment: Also you are missing the diagonal win conditions as well as an check if the field is already set

Comment: I know, it was just a demo version. im working on it right now. But thanks :)